# Why is a laptop sharing a wireles hotspot (difrent name) while "the hotspot" is disabled

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, malware, hotspot

So I recently found out, that my laptop has been sharing a network like a hotspot, but the hotspot is disabled.

This network has an ssid that changes, when i reset the wifi-card and switch on/off the wifi. It something like: **DIRECT-xx(name of my laptop)msxx** - x is for the changing upercase characters.
I also don't know what is the password to it.

Then i did some throuble-shooting, and this network disapears when the hotspot is enabled. Also, remote control of an HP is disabled.

Any one know, what this might be? A seting, malware, me beeing stupid...

I suspect it's some kind of a program, but i'm not sure.

Comment: This might be Direct WiFi. Go to the Command Prompt (cmd) and run `ipconfig /all`. Check if you see "Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter".

Comment: Just check in your settings in the network section, ho to mobile hotspot and make sure it is turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Use a packet sniffer to see if this connection is from your network or another nearby network.

Then, open Start, Settings, Network and Internet.

There is a setting to allow another device to turn ON your hotspot.  Disable (turn off) this setting,

Also run a Full Scan with Windows Defender to expose other programs or possibly a virus.

Comment: Turning that seting off didn't solve the problem. And the network is only seen by other devices arround this device, but not on this device.

Comment: Try the packet sniffer (Wire Shark) to see what is going on in your own network.  Also, run a Full Scan with Windows Defender

Comment: It was microsoft direct wifi virtual adapter. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Was my answer above helpful to you?

Comment: Yes, i actualy found a virus on my pc that was always sending something over lan connection. After that i went to disable the network cards - just to be sure that the virus doesend spread - and i found that direct wifi virtual adapter. Now i am checking all the pc's in my home. THANKS

Comment: I mentioned Packet Sniffing to help with what is around and I mentioned scanning for viruses, so overall that seems helpful.

Comment: What did you find on the other machines?